# How to modified my code to have multiple row header in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Need help to create multiple row header for datatable. I want to add header "Purpose" on top of "Web", "Database", "Application".

My current table:
[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0E7c.png)

Expected header:
[Expected header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKBo0.png)

Below is my code:

```
$('#myServerDatatable').dataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                data: serverItems,
                columns: [
                   [ {
                        title: "No",
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            return meta.row + 1; // This contains the row index
                        }
                    },
                    { title: "Hostname", data: "Hostname_server" },
                    { title: "Operating System", data: "Os_server" },
                    { title: "IP Address", rowspan: "2", data: "Ipaddress_server" },                 
                    { title: "Web", data: "Web_server"},                   
                    { title: "Database", data: "Database_server" },
                    { title: "Application", data: "App_server" },
                    { title: "Remarks", data: "Remarks_server" },
                    {
                        title: "",
                        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                            var a = '<button type="button" class="editButton"> Edit </button>';
                            var b = '<button type="button" class="deleteButton"> Delete </button>';
                            return a + " " + b;
                        }
                        }],

                ],             
            });
```

Currently I just managed to show one row header. I dont know how to make multiple row header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following snippet. You can achieve them using `rowspan` and `colspan`.

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">No</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Host Name</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Operating System</th>
                <th rowspan="2">IP Address</th>
                <th colspan="3">Purpose</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Web</th>
                <th>Database</th>
                <th>Application</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>hname 1</td>
                <td>os 1</td>
                <td>ip 1</td>
                <td>web 1</td>
                <td>db 1</td>
                <td>app 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>hname 2</td>
                <td>os 2</td>
                <td>ip 2</td>
                <td>web 2</td>
                <td>db 2</td>
                <td>app 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>hname 3</td>
                <td>os 3</td>
                <td>ip 3</td>
                <td>web 3</td>
                <td>db 3</td>
                <td>app 3</td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
```

For more details refer [THIS](http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/137556/edit)

Comment: Yes. I did the same as you suggested. We need to predefined the complex header in HTML. Just load the data later. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Alex Thats great! Don't forget to up vote since it was helpful. ;)